# How to Center Image in View Slideshow

Tags: 7, views

I can't get the views slideshow to center in the div. I tried the following code but with issue:

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_content_slideshow-block {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_content_slideshow-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The image display in few seconds but disappear afterwards.

Can anybody please help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use image styles to get all the images the same size.

Goto **Admin -> Configuration -> Media -> Image styles**

Create new image style & enter style name with a scale and crop with exact dimensions for your slideshow.

Then go back to your views slideshow setting and select **your style name** as image style.

Comment: The problem is the outer width is bigger than the slideshow width. The image is set only at 500px and the outer div width is 830px. I want to center the image within 830px div width. The ff code works great but the problem is there's a little delay after it moves to the center `#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_content_slideshow-block {
  margin: 0 auto;
}`